# Recovering deleted column in Parse

Tags: android

I deleted a column in `Parse` by mistake.

It was a photo column with many photo items, is there any method by which I can get them back?

I have tried to add the photo column back, but `Parse` tells me that `it already exists` and the previous photos are now missing so users need to upload them again.

Please suggest me how can i get them back?

Comment: May i know your database type. its MySQL or any thing else

Comment: database in parse ..

Comment: Parse itself does not have tools for recovery of deleted items

Comment: and now I have a 2 column, one is photo ( I deleted by mistake). another one is photo_thumb, it is still here, how can i import photo_thumb data to photo ?? thx